# How to set the display order of the gitlab jobs in same stage?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have several jobs that runs in the same stage sequentially. However in the GitLab UI the display order is as per job names (ascending order).

```
Job_C:
 stage: dev

Job_B:
 stage: dev
 needs: ["Job_C"]

Job_A:
 stage: dev
 needs: ["Job_B"]
```

So the job runs sequentially as expected. `Job_C` then `Job_B` and then `Job_A`. However the order of the jobs in the UI is  `Job_A`, `Job_B` and `Job_C`

Without changing the job name is there anyway to set the display order?